# Windows 8 C# GridView e.ClickedItem

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-8, indexof

I've got a `GridView` with items and an array with details about specific Items in my `GridView`.
I want  to get the Index of the clicked item, I tried to use the same code I used earlier with a `ListView`:

```
private void GridView1_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    int test = GridView1.Items.IndexOf(e.ClickedItem);
}
```

When I debug my code, int `test` will always have the value `-1`. I have no clue why this is not working and I am hoping one of you guys do.

**Edit:** Thanks for all the replies! Here is some extra information: I have disabled the `SelectionMode` since I only want to capture the index of the `ClickedItem`. I want to know the index since it is linked to my array of extra information.

Since my `SelectionMode` is set to 'None' I am not able to capture SelectedItem/SelectedIndex. I tried to enable them, but received the value '-1' again.

**Edit #2:** I have not set any `ItemSource` since I add Items manually. Could this be the problem? My `ListView` had no problems using no `ItemSource`.

**Edit #3:**

C# code:

```
TextBlock content_textblock = new TextBlock();

content_textblock.Width = 250;

content_textblock.Text = total;

content_textblock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

content_textblock.Foreground = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush"];
content_textblock.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["CaptionTextStyle"];
content_textblock.LineHeight = 30;
content_textblock.Padding = new Thickness(5, 0, 10, 15);
content_textblock.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
content_textblock.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, content_textblock.DesiredSize.Width, content_textblock.DesiredSize.Height));


StackPanel content_stackpanel = new StackPanel();
content_stackpanel.Margin = new Thickness(0, 250 - content_textblock.ActualHeight, 0, 0);
content_stackpanel.VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Top;
content_stackpanel.Height = content_textblock.Height;
content_stackpanel.Width = 250;
content_stackpanel.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush"];
content_stackpanel.Children.Add(content_textblock);


ImageBrush content_brush = new ImageBrush();
content_brush.ImageSource = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("http://ic.tweakimg.net/ext/i/thumbs_fpa_small/1357208162.jpeg")); //it is a placeholder, haha

GridView1.Items.Add(new GridViewItem { Background = content_brush, Content = content_stackpanel, Width = 250, Height = 250 });
```

XAML:

```
<GridView x:Name="GridView1" Margin="0,29,0,0" Grid.Row="2" SelectionMode="None" ItemClick="GridView1_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True"/>
```

Comment: Could be helpful http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/gridview/gridview-items-indexof-result-1.aspx

Comment: I tried and it works for me, how do you bind your GridView ?

Comment: btw. why do you need an index ?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I updated my post with new information.

Comment: Try to add items to List and then set ItemsSource with that list

Comment: I tried to reproduce your case, set SelectionMode to None and adding items directly to GridView.Items, IndexOf still working as it should. What do you get in e.ClickItem ? Same object type as you added to Items ?

Comment: could you show us the gridview markup and the code that is inserting items ?

Comment: @AntonioBakula I added the code and the XAML to my mainpost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know why you are doing this that way, it's much easier to declare controls in markup, and bind it in markup to some object poperty or similar.

But, to get index of item you should search for clicked item parent, something like this :

```
private void GridView1_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    int test = GridView1.Items.IndexOf((e.ClickedItem as FrameworkElement).Parent);
}
```

Comment: I found the answer to my own question:
I added a new global variable:

    StackPanel[] content_stackpanel = new StackPanel[99];

And I added the following in my GridView1_ItemClick

            int index = 0;
            foreach (var item in content_stackpanel)
            {
                if (item == e.ClickedItem)
                {
                    break;
                }
                index++;
            }


But your solution is working too and is better, I'll use yours.

Answer (score 1):

-1 is when none index is selected.
If You need to do something with your clicked item You can do this:

```
var item=GridView1.SelectedItem;
```

If You need only index you can do this:

```
var index= GridView1.SelectedIndex;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I updated my post with new information. This method is not working for me.